# ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to create a formset to save records in a go. But, I keep getting the error when I submit my form. And if possible please as tell me how should I save my batch of records.

My views.py:

```
def weekly_progress(request):
    ProgressFormSet = formset_factory(WeeklyProgressReportForm, extra=16)
    formset = ProgressFormSet(request.POST or None)

    if formset.is_valid():
        for f in formset:
           print(f)

    return render(request, "progress/progressentry.html", {'formset' : formset})
```

My forms.py

```
class WeeklyProgressReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = WeeklyProgressReport
       fields = ('target_date', 'this_date', 'pkgno', 'slno', 'description', 'unit', 'receipt_this_week', 'issue_this_week', 'erection_this_week')
       widgets = {
        'target_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
        'this_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
        'pkgno': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
        'slno': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
        'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 1, 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
        'unit': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
        'receipt_this_week': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'step': 0.01}),
        'issue_this_week': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'step': 0.01}),
        'erection_this_week': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'step': 0.01, 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
       }
```

My template:

```
<form id="contractor-form" method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <!-- First Row -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Select Your Package</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-lg-4">                        
                    <h4><label class="label label-primary">Package Number</label></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <select id="pkgno-select" class="form-control">                                
                        <option value="12 (BRP)">12 (BRP)</option>
                        <option value="13 (BRP)">13 (BRP)</option>
                        <option value="13 (DHB)">13 (DHB)</option>
                        <option value="14 (DHB)">14 (DHB)</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">                        
                        <button type="button" id="date-edit" class="btn btn-warning">Edit Date</button>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Second Row -->
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Quantities</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Target Date</th>
                            <th>This Date</th>
                            <th>Pkg Number</th>
                            <th>Sl Number</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Unit</th>
                            <th>Receipt This Week</th>
                            <th>Issue This Week</th>
                            <th>Erection This Week</th>                                
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for form in formset %}
                        <tr>
                           <td>{{ form.target_date }}</td>
                           <td>{{ form.this_date }}</td>
                           <td>{{ form.pkgno }}</td>
                           <td>{{ form.slno }}</td>
                           <td>{{ form.description }}</td>
                           <td>{{ form.unit }}</td>
                           <td>{{ form.receipt_this_week }}</td>
                           <td>{{ form.issue_this_week }}</td>
                           <td>{{ form.erection_this_week }}</td>                               
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Submit Button -->
    <div class="well well-lg">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My models.py

```
class WeeklyProgressReport(models.Model):
   target_date = models.DateField()
   this_date = models.DateField()
   pkgno = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   slno = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   unit = models.CharField(max_length=5)
   target_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0)
   receipt_previous = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0)
   receipt_this_week = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0)
   issue_previous = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0)
   issue_this_week = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0)
   erection_previous = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0)
   erection_this_week = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0)    

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.pkgno
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to render the management form in your template. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform) explain why and how; some selected quotes:

> This form is used by the formset to manage the collection of forms contained in the formset. If you don’t provide this management data, an exception will be raised[.]
>
> The management form is available as an attribute of the formset itself. When rendering a formset in a template, you can include all the management data by rendering `{{ my_formset.management_form }}` (substituting the name of your formset as appropriate).

Comment: http://thequickblog.com/python-django-managementform-data-is-missing-or-has-been-tampered-with/

Comment: when it comes to me, it seems that i have to use `{% for form in formset %} {{form}} {%endfor%}`  to make it work. when I just used some of the field of my model form like `{{ form.some_field}}` , I kept getting this error.

Comment: I had to add the `{{ formset.management_form }}` inside the html `<form>` tags. It didn't work otherwise

Answer (score 12):

write `{{ formset.management_form }}` above your `{% for form in formset %}`

like this

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem trying to use two formset on same page, I'm adding it's solution coz I didn't find it anywhere else.

Make sure you add the `prefix` param as

```py
formset = ProgressFormSet(request.POST or None, prefix="fs1")
```

to GET and POST request both.

Answer (score 0):

For those that ***do*** have the `{{ formset.management_form }}` in their template, and ***do*** use the correct variable name for the formset, but are ***still*** seeing the error message

```
ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with
```

#### Make sure *not* to initialize your formset with empty `data`

For example, `data=None` is no problem:

```py
>>> MyFormSet(data=None).non_form_errors()
[]
```

However, `data={}` ***is*** a problem:

```py
>>> MyFormSet(data={}).non_form_errors()
['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with. Missing fields: ...']
```

#### Beware

The latter case also arises if you try to do `MyFormSet(data=request.POST)` when handling a `GET` request, because `request.POST` will then be an *empty* `QueryDict`.

If required, a workaround would be e.g. `MyFormSet(data=request.POST or None)`.