# u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with' with Django formset

Tags: django, django-forms

I have three forms, depending on number of rooms i want to add or delete new fields "adult" and "children". For example: if value of field "room" will be 2, it should generate two couples another fields for each room 'adult' and 'children', but if change value from 2 on 1, it should delete one couple of fields. And when change the value of 'room' field from 2 to 3, it should add one couple of fields.

My forms.py:

```
class HotelForm(forms.Form):
        rooms = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Rooms'), min_value=1)

class TouristsForm(forms.Form):
        adult = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Adults'), min_value=1, initial=1)
        children = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Children'), min_value=0, initial=0, required=False)

class ChildrenAgeForm(forms.Form):
        children_age = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Children age'), min_value=2, max_value=10, initial=2, required=False
```

That's how i realize formset and validation in views.py:

```
class BookingForm(View):

        template_name = 'booking/booking.html'

        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                TouristsFormSet = formset_factory(TouristsForm, extra = 1, max_num = 15)
                ChildrenAgeFormSet = formset_factory(ChildrenAgeForm, extra = 1, max_num = 20)
                booking_form = HotelForm(prefix='booking_form')
                tourists_formset = TouristsFormSet(prefix='tourists')
                childrenage_formset = ChildrenAgeFormSet(prefix='childrenage')
                return render(request, self.template_name, { 'booking_form' : booking_form, 'tourists_formset' : tourists_formset, 'childrenage_formset' : childrenage_formset })


        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                TouristsFormSet = formset_factory(TouristsForm, extra = 1, max_num = 15)
                ChildrenAgeFormSet = formset_factory(ChildrenAgeForm, extra = 1, max_num = 20)
                booking_form = HotelForm(request.POST, prefix='booking_form')
                tourists_formset = TouristsFormSet(request.POST, prefix='tourists')
                childrenage_formset = ChildrenAgeFormSet(request.POST, prefix='childrenage')
                if booking_form.is_valid() and tourists_formset.is_valid() and childrenage_formset.is_valid():
```

I add new formset fields in the form using java-script:

```
$(function(){

   $('#id_booking_form-rooms').on('change', function(e){
      var n = $('#id_booking_form-rooms').val() || 0;
      var html = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         html += "<div>People in the room " + (i + 1) + "</div>"
         + "<br/><label for='id_tourists-" + i + "-adult'>Adults:</label>"
         + "<input id='id_tourists-" + i + "-adult' type='number' name='tourists-" + i + "-adult'/>"
         + "<label for='id_tourists-" + i + "-children'>Children:</label>"
         + "<input id='id_tourists-" + i + "-children' type='number' name='tourists-" + i + "-children' class='children_age'/>"
         + "<div class='extrafieldWrapperChAge'></div>";
       }
       $(".extrafieldWrapper").html(html);
    });

       $(".extrafieldWrapper").on('change', '.children_age', function(e){

          var n = $(this).val() || 0;
          var html = "";

          for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             html += "<br/><label for='id_childrenage-" + i + "-children_age'>Children age "+(i+1)+"</label>"
             + "<input id='id_childrenage-" + i + "-children_age' type='number' name='childrenage-" + i + "children_age' />";
          }
          $(this).next('.extrafieldWrapperChAge').html(html);
     });

 });
```

There is how look like my template:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="fieldWrapper">
          {% if booking_form.rooms.errors %}
                <ol style="list-style-type:square" >
                      {% for error in booking_form.rooms.errors %}
                             <li><strong>This field required</strong></li>
                       {% endfor %}
                 </ol>
           {% endif %}
           {{ booking_form.rooms.label_tag }}
           {{ booking_form.rooms }}
       </div>
       <div class="extrafieldWrapper">
           {{ tourists_formset.management_form }}
           {{ childrenage_formset.management_form }}
       </div>
  </div>
```

There is how look like my form in browser:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
   <label for="id_booking_form-rooms">Rooms:</label>
   <input id="id_booking_form-rooms" type="number" name="booking_form-rooms" min="1">
</div>
<div class="extrafieldWrapper">
   <div>People in the room 1</div>
   <br>
   <label for="id_tourists-0-adult">Adults:</label>
   <input id="id_tourists-0-adult" type="number" name="tourists-0-adult">
   <label for="id_tourists-0-children">Children:</label>
   <input id="id_tourists-0-children" class="children_age" type="number" name="tourists-0-children">
   <div class="extrafieldWrapperChAge">
      <br>
      <label for="id_childrenage-0-children_age">Children age 1</label>
      <input id="id_childrenage-0-children_age" type="number" name="childrenage-0children_age">
   </div>
</div>
```

But when i press submit button i always got `[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']`. What did i wrong? Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331500/managementform-data-is-missing-or-has-been-tampered-with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the number of your forms in formset on the client side, you should change the `ManagementForm` [hidden fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform): `form-TOTAL_FORMS`, `form-INITIAL_FORMS` and `form-MAX_NUM_FORMS`.

Comment: Thanks, i add in my js script `form-TOTAL_FORMS`, `form-INITIAL_FORMS`, `form-MAX_NUM_FORMS` and it works.