# Django. ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with error

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Suppose, i have two models:

1. Model Basket
2. Model Apple

One basket can have many apples in it, so there is one-to-many relationship between Basket and Apple.
For example, here is my models:

```
class Basket(models.Model):
    backet_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    owner = author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Apple(models.Model):
    apple_sort = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    apple_size = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    basket = models.ForeignKey(Basket, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="apple_in_basket")
```

I want to create a page to add basket and then to add apples to it at the same page, so i created a following forms, using formsets:

```
class NewBasketForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Basket
        exclude = ['owner']


class AddAppleToBasket(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Apple
        exclude = ['basket']

AppleFormSet = modelformset_factory(Apple, form=AddAppleToBasket, extra=1, max_num=10)
```

I want my apples to automaticly set foreign key to basket that i just created.
So i created a view to insert Basket and Apple objects to the database:

```
class BascketAddView(View):
    form_class_for_basket = NewBasketForm
    form_class_for_apples = AppleFormSet
    template_name = 'buskets/add.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        basket_form = self.form_class_for_apples()
        apples_form = self.form_class_for_answers()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'basket_form': basket_form, 'apples_form': apples_form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        basket_form = self.form_class_for_basket(request.POST)
        apple_form = self.form_class_for_apples(request.POST)
        if basket_form.is_valid() and apple_form.is_valid():
            print("form is valid!!!")
            new_basket = basket_form.save(commit=False)
            new_basket.owner = request.user
            new_basket.save()
            instances = apple_form.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.basket = new_basket
                instance.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

        print("form is invalid")
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'basket_form': busket_form, 'apples_form': apples_form})
```

The form is rendering just fine, but when i fill it and submit i get "form is invalid" in the console.
What am i doing wrong?

In template, {{ apple_form.non_form_error }} gives me following error:

```
ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with. Missing fields: form-TOTAL_FORMS, form-INITIAL_FORMS. If the issue persists, you may need to file a bug report.
```

Comment: add `print(basket_form.errors) and print(apple_form.errors)` to first of all drill down the error

Comment: print(basket_form.errors) is empty.
print(apple_form.errors) returns []. So, that means there are no errors? 
Wierd.

Comment: {{ apple_form.non_form_error }} prints "ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with. Missing fields: form-TOTAL_FORMS, form-INITIAL_FORMS. If the issue persists, you may need to file a bug report." on template.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331500/managementform-data-is-missing-or-has-been-tampered-with)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution!

Well, if anyone will stumble оn this type of error, try adding `{{ formset.management_form }}` in your template where form is rendered, inside `<form method="post>` tag:

So, in my case i should add:

```
  <form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {{ apple_form.management_form }}
    {% for form in apple_form %}
  </form>
```

More info in the Django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/